# Backtracking a Javascript Button

Tags: javascript, html

My question is, How do I backtrack what a javascript button does. Specifically when it does not have an obvious function as detailed below.

I am taking a JS course on Udacity and I'm trying to figure out what happens when I hit the Submit Button.  Is this possible and if so, what is the next piece I need to search for?

Currently the button looks like this:

```html
<li>
  <button type="button" class="index--primary--P14pO index--_btn--9nYKH  index--standard--3U4zZ" style="cursor: pointer;">Submit Answer</button>
</li>
```

I am assuming I do not need to look in the .css files that reference this class.  The .js file I found referencing this class only calls it out in this function:

```js
function(e,t){
  e.exports= {
    _btn:"index--_btn--9nYKH",
    primary:"index--primary--P14pO index--_btn--9nYKH",
    default:"index--default--2h8DE index--primary--P14pO index--_btn--9nYKH",
    secondary:"index--secondary--1FbZp index--_btn--9nYKH",
    large:"index--large--OBS6N",
    standard:"index--standard--3U4zZ",
    small:"index--small--ACszC",
    nav:"index--nav--2dHWq index--_btn--9nYKH",
    body:"index--body--3i32b index--_btn--9nYKH"
  }
}
```

Here I am at a loss as to what to search for.  This .js file is very large, is there something I can search for that tells me how the function(e,t) works?

Thanks.

Comment: I took some coursework at Udacity. I can guarantee that's not what you should be looking at. In order to track down what's happening in a button you can use the console(ctrl+shift+j in chrome) or right click the button and select "Inspect" - on the right hand side you'll see "styles" and a few tabs. Check out Event Listeners and look at `click` specifically. It should give you a reference point.

Comment: Furthermore Udacity has it's own forums that would be able to help you out a bit more with the info you're providing. Otherwise you're going to need to provide quite a bit more information that might be difficult for you to properly display since you seem a bit new and you're not familiar with the codebase.

Comment: @zfrisch I believe this answered my question.  It looks like there is a script on click that collects my input and sends it to an API for validation.

Comment: @zfrisch If I was going to draw a flow chart from the button to the push request to the API, what should I be looking for?  Currently my flowchart stops at the above function.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

- Create a HTML file, which in your case would be called 'Submit.html'.
- Inside Submit.html type in

  ```
  <script src="name_of_js_file.js"></script>
  ```
- This will direct back to the button js file.
- If you want to run another javascript script after this, then do the following:

  ```
  <script src="name_of_first_js_file"></script>
  <script src="name_of_second_js_file"></script>
  ```

  It is simple to use and is effective.

  I hope this is of use to you.

Comment: This was interesting.  After running that program and inspecting the code I have a better idea how Udacity is pulling and pushing results.  I still don't see the javascript code that causes the submit button to do anything different than any other button however.